# Server Harddrive Defragment

Tags: windows-server-2003, defragmentation

We have a database server with U2 installed on a windows 2003 server with RAID5 setup. I'm wanting to use Diskkeeper to defragment the different partitions. Has anyone ever ran into any issues or data loss when defragmenting a drive? Are there any dangers when defragging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Except it makes NO SENSE on a properly conffigured SQL Server (if your partitions are aligned, node size is set correctly to the NOT DEFAULT value).

Comment: No benefit to the data/log files, maybe. But the rest of the file system benefits just as much as any other system.

Comment: The rest of the system is irrelevant, though. Seriously. Once SQL is loaded, and if properly configured, the pretty much ONLY load you have is on the data and log files. Which, under proper guideliney, are static in size.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Other than defragmenting the filesystem there may be a way of defragmenting the database itself (i.e. how data are stored *inside* the database files) . The exact procedure depends on the database product you're using though.